# Monodromy representations are "quasi-unipotent"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fundamental-group, monodromy, local-systems

Let $S$ be a smooth complex algebraic variety, let $b$ be a closed point of $X$, and let $f:X\to S$ be a polarized family of smooth projective varieties over $S$. This induces a monodromy representation $$\pi_1(S) \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{H}^i_{prim}(X_b,\mathbb Z))\subset \mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb  C).$$ (Here $N$ is the dimension of $\mathrm{H}^i$, and $\pi_1(S)$ denotes the topological fundamental group of $S(\mathbb C)$.)

Clearly, this representation is not "quasi-unipotent".

But can we find a set of generators, say $g_1,\ldots, g_n$ of $\pi_1(S)$, such that each $g_i$ acts quasi-unipotently?

The problem is maybe clearest to see when $S$ is projective. In this case, there is no "boundary", so how to get the set of generators to be quasi-unipotent?

PS. I could not extract what I'm asking from [Quasi-unipotent monodromy for general families](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102802/quasi-unipotent-monodromy-for-general-families) unfortunately.

Comment: The answer is no, in general. If S is a compact Shimura variety which is a closed subvariety of the moduli of ppav with "high" level structure, then you get a family of abelian variety parametrised by S. The level structure ensures that there are no torsion elements in the fundamental group of S, and compactness of S ensures there are no unipotent elements in $\pi _1(S )$

Comment: @Venkataramana Thank you for your comment. I think I'm missing the argument for why "compactness of $S$ ensures $\pi_1(S)$ has no unipotent elements". How does one prove that?

Comment: the Shimura variety S is of the form $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ where $G$ is a Hermitian type real semi-simple group and $K$ its maximal compact subgroup. Thus, the compactness is equivalent to the compactness of $\Gamma\backslash G$. If $\Gamma $ s a co-compact arithmetic subgroup of $G$, then $\Gamma$ cannot contain unipotent elements (this is the easier part of the Godement criterion; you can find it in Raghunathan's book on discrete subgroups of Lie groups).

Comment: @Venkataramana This is a really nice example!

Comment: @Dan Litt Thank you!

Comment: @Venkataramana Ok, I understand. This answers my question. I was just confused because I thought you were saying that, for all smooth projective varieties $S$, the fundamental group $\pi_1(S)$ has no unipotent elements (with respect to any   faithful linear representation). But that's not true right?

Comment: No, I was not saying that. For example, the fundamental group of an ellptic curve is the free abelian group on two generators, and you can find (even faithful) representation, with every element unipotent.